# Early 65C816 CPU's SEP and REP instruction are followed by a NOP?

Tags: assembly, 65816

Why did early versions of the 65C816 CPU need a suffixed NOP to every SEP and REP instruction? I saw comments in some source code pointing at this. Looking around in official WDC's documentation and others didn't reveal even a hint on this subject.

Comment: Are you able to cite any source code that does this?

Comment: The original comment was "NOP necessary for early versions of '802/'816 >4MHz.", mentioned in a source code of a Forth implementation which is not publicly available. A connection to a timing issue seems obvious ...

Comment: Fourth hand info from usenet: "one of the engineers from AE once told me
that Mensch had told him that the problem with certain instructions not working at high speeds was the physical distance that some of the signals had to travel inside the chip. ".  I vaguely recall hearing GTE fixed some problems and those changes were incorporated back into faster CPUs.

Comment: Another usenet post (comp.sys.apple2, 1990): "Bill Mensch did a good job on the instruction set, but his mask leaves a lot to be desired since it does not lend itself to high speed operation. Unless they've fixed things, on the 8 mhz parts REP and SEP take 250 ns to operate so you have to put a NOP after each one OR you have to stretch the clock the way the transwarp does. WDC has admitted that this is caused by very long signal lines."

Comment: And another CSA2 post claims WDC fixed the REP/SEP timing issues in 1992.

Comment: Although it doesn't apply in this case, there have been highly pipelined architectures which require a NOP after a RET type instruction.  Unless you were writing assembler code, you'd never notice.  For some architectures programmers were specifically told to **not** program in assembly because of unobvious dependencies between machine code and hardware.

Comment: @KelvinSherlock. That seems like an answer to me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The original 65816 layout was done by hand and was [not amenable to high speeds](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.sys.apple2/lw8eP8h-izA/jsGMZyxdjiUJ). In particular, `REP`/`SEP` (perhaps `PLP` as well) instructions didn't complete in 3 cycles when overclocked. (Even today, the data sheet notes, "the MX [pin] output is invalid during the instruction cycle following REP, SEP and PLP instruction execution").

The Transwarp GS accelerator stretched clock cycles to work around that problem.

In 1992, a Sanyo redesign fixed the issues and enabled higher speeds.

(Sourced from comp.sys.apple2 archives and GEnie A2 Transwarp GS archives)

Comment: SEP and REP are two-byte instructions which perform an operation which is nominally simpler than ADC #imm, which takes 2 cycles in 8-bit mode.  It would thus be logical for SEP/REP to take 2 cycles.  The fact that it takes 3 (according to current documentation) suggests that the "fix" was to add an extra cycle, effectively building the NOP previously required into the instruction itself.

Comment: They took 3 cycles in old documentation (dating back to 1985) too. That's a good point and it very well could be that, during development, WDC increased the cycle count to compensate for a poor layout.

Answer (score 6):

I am not an expert on this processor or its history but this sounds like the sort of silicon bug that I have had to deal with on many processors over the years.  It is often the case that there are timing problems with early versions of the silicon for a given processor that then require a software workaround. These are normally detailed in a processor errata sheet published by the device manufacturer.  Typically compiler writers will fix their code generators to produce code that adds any extra workaround instructions automatically, some even have compile time switches that allow the programmer to specify which silicon revision their code is to use.  If the workaround is simple than the problem may never be fixed and it just becomes a "feature".

I have looked for a WDC errata sheet for their processor but without success.

[Example MSP430 errata sheet from Texas Instruments](http://www.ti.com/lit/er/slaz197h/slaz197h.pdf)